# div position absolute inside another div that stretches

Tags: css, html

I have writen the following code but from some reason i cant get the box height to stretch I have used overflow but nothing :(

As soon as I remove the content_body position absolute then the content div stretches.

```css
#content{
    background-image:url(../../../images2/bg.png);
    width:1001px;
    height:auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-top:16px;
}
#content_body{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:6;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="content_body">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats ur question? cant get u...

Comment: If you use position:absolute then the element doesn't have a width or height.

Comment: So how can i get #content to stretch to the same height as #content_body?

Comment: #content already streches to #content_body with no additional CSS, since it's the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `position:absolute` instead use `position:relative` as an absolute positioned element has no height or width.

You can specify the height on the div. For example `height:100px`

Answer (score 0):

use position:relative instead of position:absolute... The content_body size ll be increased based on content.... [see this fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya/wUxhC/)